# apache log level - ignore module

Tags: loglevel

Is it possible to setup `Loglevel` so that it will ignore a specific module, such as `ssl_engine_io.c` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, anything is possible. You have the source. :) However, there is no way to do it without recompiling.

Anyway, the log level is set in the server_rec struct, implying it is set per-vhost.

The ap_log_* functions get the file and line info of the caller so it would be possible to hack this feature into the source in a general way.

Comment: lol, bleh.  So there's no simple way ^_^